# Using a custom threshold value with tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm working on a binary classification problem and I'm using the tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier class within TensorFlow. When invoking this estimator for only 2 classes, it uses a threshold value of 0.5 as the cutoff between the 2 classes. I'd like to know if there's a way to use a custom threshold value since this might improve the model's accuracy.

I've searched all around the web and apparently there isn't a way to do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier` class has a method called `predict_proba` which returns the probabilities belonging to each class for the given inputs. Then you can use something like, `tf.round(prob+thres)` for binary thresholding with the custom parameter `thres`.

Comment: wow I haven't seen this in any documentation I'll try it now. Thank you!

Comment: actually now that I went back to the man page I remember seeing it but I hadn't thought of using it like that

Comment: If the above solved your problem, can you consider accepting the answer by check-marking it.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that would help