# Map the output values of a network in 0 or 1 TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, loss-function, softmax

I have a network with the output layer of size `[3, 13000, 3, 1] (B,H,W,C)` and I transformed it using `tf.reduce_mean` to obtain an output size `[3, 13000, 1]`.

Graphically is this [image]

Is right?

My labels are in the size of `[3, 13000, 1]` as my new output and are all values 0 or 1.

Now I have to compute the loss with the labels. To compute this loss I use this formula `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=predict, labels=y))`, but first I have to transform all the values in the output in 0 or 1. I'm using the `tf.nn.softmax` function but I get all 1.

How can I implement a function that maps all the values under a threshold to 0 and above 1? And this threshold should be for example `(max value - min value) / 2`. This should also work with the gradient in the backprop step.

Comment: The output is obtained with a relu function so its values are [0, x], but I need [0, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your prediction is a single class value, when you apply `softmax` on it, its going to be always 1 irrespective of the value: `(exp(predict)/sum(exp(predict)) = exp(predict)/exp(predict) = 1)`. Either convert the input to `one-hot` and make the model predict two classes: [0, 1] or use `sigmoid cross entropy` instead.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain very well. My output is [3, 13000, 1] of random values because I removed the relu and they are coming from several conv layers. The target has the same shape and inside I have values 0 or 1 but is not a one hot vector. What I have to do is to match the first element of the output with the first element of the target and check if these are equal or not and do that for all elements.

Comment: Your output `class labels` for each of those 3x1300 output is still 1 (so you will get all 3x1300 as 1). You need to use sigmoid if you want to keep the same dimensions. For `softmax` your model logits should output [3, 13000,2] to predict 2 classes 0 or 1 for that labels needs to be one-hot encoded.

Comment: Ok, I understand what softmax wants, but I need the dimensions to remain these, so I'm not going to use it from now on. What I looking for is a built-in function or something to turn my output values in 0 or 1. Example [-3.412, 1.5, 7.521] -> [0, 0, 1]. Then to compute the loss I've found a way using other function and not softmax_cross_entropy.

Comment: Use sigmoid, your nn will adjust the thresholds by learning and outputs between 0 and 1.

Comment: I've tried to use it before posting on Stack but it gave values on 0.5-1 and not 0-1 but now works. That's weird. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I realized now that the output is not either 0 or 1 but it's between them. I need something that gives me 0 or 1 only these two values. Do you know a function to do that?

Comment: `tf.round`. Check:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856964/using-a-custom-threshold-value-with-tf-contrib-learn-dnnclassifier/44857779#44857779